# How to update resume to answer certain questions asked by recruiter?

Tags: email, recruiting

After sending an HR rep my CV, I received an email response asking for an updated copy that answered a list of questions she provided. I am not sure how to include the answers in my resume - especially since almost all the questions are "yes or no" questions or questions you answer with one word. How should I add these answers to my resume? If the questions are already implicitly answered, do I need to answer them explicitly?

She also asked for my Facebook - is this normal? (though I have included my LinkedIn account already)

Comment: Can you give some examples of these questions?

Answer (score 1):

> I received an email from HR representative after sending her my CV, she asked for an update copy that answer some questions. I am not sure how to include the answers especially that almost all the question are (yes/no) questions and questions you answer with one word, how to add it to my resume? and if it's implicitly mentioned do I need to answer it explicitly?

I wouldn't update the CV to answer the questions unless you really feel they're relevant and belong on the CV - I'd include an updated cover note that answers them explicitly. (If you do choose to answer some on the CV, I'd still refer to it in the cover note to make it clear.)

> and she asked for my facebook is this normal? (though I included my linkedin account already)

No, that's not normal (at least in my experience.) I'm assuming it's not directly relevant to the job in any way? If so, then that would be the exception to the rule. (It's very normal they'll try to look for it, but that's different to being passed it explicitly.)

You *could* just give it to them, but bear in mind they could use any public photo, status, or status that you're tagged in against you. If it were me, I'd lock it down so no-one can find it if they're not your friend already, then just reply with "I'm afraid I don't have a public Facebook profile."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what she means by answering her questions in your resume is that she's suggesting your resume is lacking certain content she feels is important in order to market you to her client; unless she is a recruiter from within the target employer's organization.

Typically in my experience if a recruiter asked me questions they felt my resume didn't cover, it was their way of saying that I needed to fill in missing content such as experience with a specific technology.

Asking for your Facebook profile link is odd, but it isn't; depending on what country the position is in. If the name your name referenced in your question is your true name, then the recruiter may be wanting to further screen you to see what kind of affiliations you may have, or they may not. Again, without knowing the country you're working in and where the recruiter and position are based out of, the best one can do on the Facebook profile request is speculate.

It's becoming increasingly more common for employers to check your social media,even if they don't tell you they did so. If you maintain a social media presence, then its fair game for a recruiter/employer to look you up. What is not legal thus far (Speaking from within the United States) is for an employer to ask you for direct access to your Facebook account unless you are applying for a gov't contract or direct gov't employment requiring a secret or higher security clearance and full financial disclosures. However that does not sound like your case.

My advice in answering her questions, is to answer them by providing good well thought out and clear explanations of your work history, time frames, and what value you added to the organization  during your time with that employer.Any questions that aren't answered by a well formulated resume can be answered as an addendum follow up after the fact. You don't want to clutter up your resume with what can be answered in a 3 minute email.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to include the answers especially that almost all the question are (yes/no) questions and questions you answer with one word, how to add it to my resume?

You need to phrase or structure your resume in such a way that accommodates your need to explain your roles and experiences that answers the questions they've provided. You can do this in a number of ways and it'll vary per person as to how well it comes across, but here are some examples;

`Can you use Git (version control) - *for (IT) development jobs*`

- I have experience with version control systems, these include things such as Git and SVN for tracking code changes in software and have been using these types of systems for many years now which has allowed me to improve my confidence in using them.

`Can you cook a really tasty dish? - *for cooking jobs*`

- Not only do I have experience in cooking very tasty food, I've also spent many years learning recipes in my spare time and improving my technique from family and friends by cooking regularly for them.

You get the idea. Answer the question in the first line but give a short example. Fit this sort of thing in where you can, but don't disrupt the flow of your resume and stick it in the middle because it'll look strange.

Alternatively, list the things you're good at.

1. *Excellent time keeper.*
2. *Works very well as part of a team.*
3. *Very customer focused and keen problem solver.*

Again, make it natural. Imagine they're asking you these questions in person. You probably wouldn't just answer with a yes or no and stop talking. You'd flesh out the question a bit more and make it into a conversation. Do that but write it down.

> asked for my Facebook - is this normal?

Normal might not be the right word, but more and more common for sure. Employers and recruiters will do this because they want to see what you're like around friends and family. Are you that person that likes to constantly rant all day? Do you like to start arguments and be confrontational? LinkedIn is fine, but it's business facing and not personal. They want to see what you're really like as a person.

You could decline to provide a link but that might come across in a negative light like you have some to hide. The alternative is to lock your account down so things are private and ensure you're happy with what is public. When posting stuff on social media, try and think how a boss would react if you were giving them a piece of paper (or a link) with your social media content on it. Make sure it's appropriate.